# Find which friends og.liked a specific object

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I am using this following Graph API request to get all friends who likes a specific object:

```
me/?fields=friends.fields(likes.target_id(searched_object_id))
```

iOS code is as follow:

```
[ FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath: [ NSString stringWithFormat: @"me/?fields=friends.fields(name,likes.target_id(%lld))", 7919071058 ]
                 completionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                     [ [ [ result objectForKey: @"friends" ] objectForKey: @"data" ] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id friend, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                         if ( [ friend objectForKey: @"likes" ] )
                             NSLog( @"%@ also likes that", [ friend objectForKey: @"name" ] );
                     } ];
                 }
 ];
```

I'd like to do the same with og.likes unfortunately .target_id is not available

For information og.likes are open graph object you can declare in your app.(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/)

Thanks by advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here follow modified code to work with og.likes

```
[ FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath: @"me/?fields=friends.fields(name,og.likes)"
                     completionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                         [ [ [ result objectForKey: @"friends" ] objectForKey: @"data" ] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id friend, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                             [ [ [ friend objectForKey: @"og.likes" ] objectForKey: @"data" ] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id ogLike, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                                 if ( [ [ [ [ ogLike objectForKey: @"data" ] objectForKey: @"object" ] objectForKey: @"id" ] isEqualToString: [ NSString stringWithFormat: @"%lld", idObject ] ] )
                                     NSLog( @"%@ also og.likes that", [ friend objectForKey: @"name" ] );
                             } ];
                         } ];
                     }
 ];
```

As you can see, i had to grab every og.likes of my friends then iterate through them to find matching one. It is more bandwidth but it works.
If anyone find a more elegant way, i am still curious about it.

Regards